# Android Studio keeps Crashing

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, windows-10

I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Ever since I've been using Windows 10, Android Studio has been crashing. It starts and tries loading the project, and then crashes. If I press cancel while it's loading the project, it goes to the new project/open a project start screen. At this point it's stable, so it must be something to do with opening the projects. I know that the projects aren't corrupted because I've made new ones and they crash too. If I look at the bottom right where the loading description is, it works until 'indexing files' ends.

I've scoured the web for hours and hours, but to no avail. I added system variables, I deleted a registry key, I reinstalled the program twice, and I even downgraded to Windows 7 to see if it would work on that OS (it did).

Any help to get it to run would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I had this same problem on Windows 7 after importing my project from eclipse.

Comment: @jtooker i am also facing same issue, How would you solve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run Android Studio "as administrator"

Comment: Is this solved the issue? I just recently update from android studio 3.4 to 3.5 and while it loading user setting, it crashes fast, i click fast and can't manage to catch the exception. Now, android studio keeps crashing.

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest the following solution:

1. Run your Android Studio 2-3 times, 3rd time is usually the charm :)

---

If it doesn't work.

1. Go to your project directory and open CMD in that directory. type in

   ```
   run gradlew.bat OR gradlew.bat
   ```
2. Let it refresh the gradle files.
3. Start your android studio

Comment: I am usually quite sceptical about 'switch it on and off' type answers. My android studio was behaving badly after a pc crash. On the third start, it worked!!

Comment: awesome.... :D
sometimes if it doesn't work, just reinstall the android studio after backup... :)

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the website http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
it doesn't support windows 10 yet so you might have to downgrade to windows 7 for awhile or wait till they update the software 
"System Requirements
Windows

Microsoft® Windows® 8/7/Vista/2003 (32 or 64-bit)
2 GB RAM minimum, 4 GB RAM recommended"

Comment: Do you think it'd be a bad idea to keep Windows 10 and just use a virtual machine for Android Studio?

Comment: No reason not to as long as your computer can handle it